# Postgres implicitly shaped temporary tables. Syntactic sugar I am not aware of?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, syntactic-sugar

I'm writing a batch mode update function and at the moment it looks like this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gen_category_counts()
RETURNS VOID as $$
BEGIN
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE category_stats ON COMMIT DROP AS
    WITH
        PC as(
            SELECT category_id, COUNT(*)
            FROM forum_posts fp
            INNER JOIN forum_topics ft
            ON ft.forum_id = fp.forum_id
            AND ft.id = fp.topic_id
            GROUP BY category_id
       ), 
        tc as(
            SELECT category_id, COUNT(*)
            FROM forum_topics
            GROUP BY category_id 
        )
    SELECT tc.category_id,tc.count AS topic_count, pc.count AS post_count
    FROM tc,pc
    WHERE tc.category_id = pc.category_id;

    UPDATE forum_category_nodes fcn 
    set post_count = category_stats.post_count, topic_count = category_stats.topic_count
    from category_stats
    where fcn.id = category_stats.category_id; 
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Is there some syntactic sugar that is better than having to write out a whole sentence to declare a temp table that lives only for the duration of the function ?

Sql Server has a `select into #tablename` (can't remember the exact syntax, it could be @tablename). I have seen this style of syntax used on the mailing lists, but it's syntactically incorrect, also the EBBF `select into` [documentation mentions temporary tables as well right next to the `into` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-selectinto.html).

So if postgres does have better sugar for implicitly defined scoped temporary tables, what is it ? :D

p.s., I'm going to be writing procedures with hundreds of lines of logic and these things add up :D

Comment: Writing of stored procedures in PostgreSQL and SQL server is relative different - PostgreSQL has not procedures, has not table variables, MSSQL has not arrays ... so usually you have to change your style

Comment: Ofcourse :D but regardless of what metaphors are in use, I'd still expect the same type of sugar to carry over :D

Answer (score 1):

OK, one minor shortcut:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE category_stats ON COMMIT DROP AS
```

Other than that, for all I know, you are using the simplest form in your question - and I have been using temporary tables *a lot* over the last couple of years.

Honestly, I don't see why a few descriptive key words should bother me.