# Postgres implicit type inferencing from select statements

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, syntactic-sugar

I asked a [similar questions yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551627/postgres-implicitly-shaped-temporary-tables-syntactic-sugar-i-am-not-aware-of) about postgress, and if it could inference the type from the result shape of a select statement.

Today I want to return a resultset from a query, this is the query that I have found to work :

```
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS topic_result_entry CASCADE;
CREATE TYPE topic_result_entry AS
(
    id            INTEGER,  
    last_post_at  TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
    is_sticky     BOOLEAN,
    is_poll       BOOLEAN,
    has_prefix    BOOLEAN,
    prefix        CHARACTER VARYING,
    title         CHARACTER VARYING,
    post_count    INTEGER,
    started_by    INTEGER,
    started_at    TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_paginated_topics(
    forum_id_ INTEGER, category_id_ INTEGER, page_number_ INTEGER, topics_per_page_ INTEGER)
RETURNS SETOF topic_result_entry as $$
DECLARE
    zero_based_index INTEGER;
    lower_offset INTEGER;
    upper_offset INTEGER;

BEGIN                    
    zero_based_index := page_number_ -1;
    lower_offset := zero_based_index * topics_per_page_;
    upper_offset := ( (topics_per_page_ * page_number_) + 1 );               

    RETURN query
    select id,last_post_at, is_sticky, is_poll, 
           has_prefix, prefix, title,post_count, 
           started_by, started_at 
    from (
        select row_number() OVER(ORDER by last_post_at desc) as rn, * 
        from forum_topics where category_id = category_id_ and forum_id= forum_id_
    ) as foo
    where rn > lower_offset and rn < upper_offset;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The shape of the resultset can be infered from the parameter list of the select + the schema definition of the source table.

Q1. Is there some syntactic sugar in 9.1, and if not is this on the roadmap ?

Q2 is there a less verbose way of doing this ?

**offtopic**

```
select id,last_post_at, is_sticky, is_poll, 
       has_prefix, prefix, title,post_count, 
       started_by, started_at 
from (
    select row_number() OVER(ORDER by last_post_at desc) as rn, * 
    from forum_topics where category_id = 72
) as foo
where rn>0 and rn<22

QUERY PLAN  
Subquery Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..492.20 rows=28 width=60)  
  Filter: ((foo.rn > 0) AND (foo.rn < 22))  
  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.00..409.42 rows=5519 width=156)    
        ->  Index Scan using forum_topics_last_post_at_idx1 on forum_topics  (cost=0.00..326.63 rows=5519 width=156)    
              Filter: (category_id = 72)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntactical sugar? I got some for you.

If ...

> The shape of the resultset can be inferred from [...] the **schema definition of the source table**

... then you can much simplify. In PostgreSQL a table definition automatically defines a type of the same name.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_paginated_topics(
    _forum_id int, _category_id int, _page_number int, _topics_per_page int)
RETURNS SETOF forum_topics AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
   _lower_offset  int := (_page_number - 1) * _topics_per_page;
   _upper_offset  int := _topics_per_page * _page_number + 1;
BEGIN

   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT *
   FROM   forum_topics f
   WHERE  f.category_id = category_id_
   AND    f.forum_id = forum_id_
   ORDER  BY f.last_post_at DESC
   LIMIT  _lower_offset
   OFFSET _upper_offset;

END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Other details:

- Use LIMIT / OFFSET as @user272735 pointed out.

  - Then you can use `SELECT *`, because you got rid of the extra column.
- You can assign variables at declaration time.
- Short type names.
- Removed redundant parenthesis.
- I added a table alias and table qualification to the query, which is not necessary in this case, but good practice to avoid naming conflicts in plpgsql functions.

Comment: Thank you, I guess this is as close as it gets --i.e., shaping the table by using the `select new-shape-fields from stored_function(...);`. I didn't even consider that approach.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL provides [LIMIT and OFFSET](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-limit.html) that can be used to limit a result set. E.g.

```
select id, last_post_at, is_sticky, is_poll, 
       has_prefix, prefix, title, post_count, 
       started_by, started_at 
  from forum_topics
 where category_id = category_id_ and forum_id = forum_id_
 order by id
 limit topics_per_page_
offset (page_number_ - 1) * topics_per_page_
;
```

Comment: +1, but since it was an offtopic issue, and ideas on the syntactic sugar I was talking about ? If you can answer Q1 and Q2 i'll accept :D

Comment: Oh wow, limit and offset are 5-10 times faster then the querry I wrote out :D

Answer (score 0):

I am not an export in Postgres-specific features, but pagination is generally a little tricky in SQL. In ANSI SQL, I would typically do a SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... to determine the size of my result set and then use a cursor to get the pages a user wants. Your query computes the size of the result set for each page, which could become inefficient. Also keep in mind that the size of the result set can change as new records are added, so pages may not properly align with each other.

Comment: There is an index on the `last_post_at` field and I'd expect the query compiler to have correct statistics on the index to quickly determine which subset of the index meets the `where` clause. I'd be extremely surprised if the query compiler and execution engine can't do this. Also I have done this type of pagination in SQL server and it works as I described above. Once I have enough data I'll take a look at the query plan and post back :D

Comment: Also this is a bit off-topic. Also I expect the queries to behave statelessly, who cares if a new topic enters the forum between pagination. It's how a web-based forum works.

Comment: (see edit) Hmm, it doesn't take the where clause from the outer query into account when performing the subquery. I'll have to take a look at rewriting the query if possible. I could just do the row numbering in batch mode tho since I am not spidering the forums in realtime.